# given an iterator, declare an index with correct size_type

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, decltype, typename

In a C++ template, I struggle to define a variable with the correct `size_type`. Basically, this will be an index type into the container. I know that `int` works but would like to have it in a clean form.

```
template<typename ForwardIt> 
void test(ForwardIt it) {
    // this yields the underlying type
    decltype(typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type()) T;

    // what I would like is something like above, but yielding the
    // correct size_type for the container.

    // Something like this but with the type extracted from ForwardIt:
    std::vector<int>::size_type i; 

    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you want to be able to do with this number? Possibly you want `iterator_traits<It>::difference_type`? Given an iterator, in general you can't index into the container itself (it might be a container that doesn't support that, for example).

Comment: You can get `difference_type`.  There isn't a way to get `size_type` from the container the iterator is from

Comment: @NathanOliver - I think you mean "Iterator", not "container"

Comment: @MarshallClow No, I meant container.  *what I would like is something like above, but yielding the
    // correct size_type for the container.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on what @NathanOliver said:  Iterators don't have `size_type`s; they have a `difference_type`, which represents the distance between two iterators. Containers have a `size_type`.

An iterator need not have an associated container, so there's no way to get "the container's `size_type`" from just an iterator.

Comment: To be clear: When you say, "an iterator need not have an associated container", do you mean "...need not have an associated container _type_" (because that's what the corresponding `size_type` is tied to), or a container _instance_?

Comment: In that case, the reasoning in your last sentence is invalid. Even if the iterator has no associated container _instance_, it has an associated container _type_, and that container's `size_type` should be obtainable.

Comment: I disagree. `char *` is an iterator. What's the container type?  Might be `vector<char>`, might be `string`, might be `array<char, N>`, might be some user-defined container, might be a single `char`.  No way to tell.

Comment: @MaxLanghof -- `char ch; char* silly_iterator = &ch;`. No container, no `size_type`. But a valid iterator. A more serious example would be `std::istream_iterator<char> iter(std::cin);`. Again, no container, no `size_type`. Containers are the most common way of creating a sequence that can be managed with iterators, but they are not the only way.